# Input format for uDeploy Deployment in Servicenow

Tags: javascript, json, servicenow, orchestration, udeploy

I'm integrating uDeploy with ServiceNow and need to know if JSON is the only format that can be provided as input in the workflow of ServiceNow for Udeploy deployment or are there any other formats?

Comment: Can you include some more details as you can write a script to parse whatever, however, I'm not sure I entirely follow.